# Is it possible to ignore required type used with @include in graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql

Is it possible to ignore the required type (in this situation, type input of `createCarEvent` contains variable `$from` as `String!`) when using `@include`? I tried to use `$from` as `String` instead of `String!` but it led to an exception:

> Variable "$from" of type "String" used in position expecting type "String!"

The `$isNeedCreateCarEvent` checks if two variables (`$from` and `$to`) exist.

```
mutation rejectBooking(... $from: String, $to: String, $isNeedCreateCarEvent: Boolean!) {
...
createCarEvent(
  input: {
    ...
    from: $from
    to: $to
  }
) @include(if: $isNeedCreateCarEvent) {
  ...eventItem
}
```

The scheme:

```
    input CarEventInput {
    ...
    from: String!
    to: String
  }
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to ignore types.

Comment: Please show us (the relevant parts of) your schema definition. Without that we hardly will be able to help.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for GraphQL to know that `$from` is always supplied if `$isNeedCreateCarEvent` is `true`, the type declarations cannot express that (and your calling code cannot guarantee that).

You better use two separate mutations, one with the `createCarEvent` and one without, if you want to make `$from` and `$to` optional.

If that would mean too much repetition for you (because of the rest of the query), the only way is to declare the parameters as non-null and pass empty strings as dummy values when using `$isNeedCreateCarEvent = false`.